# Making an Android project Open Source?

Tags: android, github, open-source

I've developed an Android app and I wont have enough time to maintain it in the future (~300k downloads, ~3 updates), I'm thinking of making it open-source so maybe other programmers can help me.

I never used Git-Hub or other similar sites, is there a detailed step-by-step on how to upload an Android project and how to maintain it? What are the most important things to consider when making an app open source?

I should note that I dont have any experience with any open source project.

Comment: +1 for your good intention

Comment: What is the project?  Your main issue will be keeping binary assets out of the repo.

Comment: Why? If binary assets are needed, they should be included.

Comment: More signing certificates than random binary assets.  Independent builds should be signed with their own certificate, not yours.

Answer (score 1):

Git was designed specifically to suit the needs of open source development communities. The best guide I have found is on git's web site: http://git-scm.com/book/ That guide will quickly (about an hour of reading) and clearly (has great examples and diagrams) explain everything you need to know to get started with git.

For hosting your project, there are several free hosts that support git, such as Github or Bit Bucket.

Important considerations when making your project open source are choosing an appropriate license and determining who you give admin access to the repository (copy of the project) on your host.

Good Luck!
Chris